# Getting cummulative count with plyr in R

Tags: r, plyr

I have a data frame with around 70,000 rows and I am trying to get a count dependent on date-time variables> I have been using plyr for my other analysis but this one is just not working. My dataframe is as below:

```
Create.Date.Time        Service         Closing.Date.Time
1   2013-06-01 12:59:00 AV              2013-06-01 13:59:00
2   2013-06-02 07:56:00 SERVICE684793   2013-06-02 08:59:00
3   2013-06-02 09:39:00 SERVICE684793   2013-06-03 12:01:00
4   2013-06-02 14:14:00 SERVICE684796   2013-06-02 14:55:00
5   2013-06-02 17:20:00 SERVICE684797   2013-06-03 12:06:00
6   2013-06-03 07:20:00 SERVICE684793   2013-06-03 07:39:00
7   2013-06-03 08:02:00 SERVICE684839   2013-06-03 12:09:00
8   2013-06-03 08:04:00 SERVICE684841   2013-06-04 08:05:00
9   2013-06-03 08:04:00 SERVICE684841   2013-06-05 08:06:00
10  2013-06-03 08:08:00 SERVICE684841   2013-06-03 08:08:00
```

My aim is to obtain the number of observations for each which has been closed by each Create.Date.Time. I do not want to use for loops since that will take forever. 
I wanted to use plyr, with the function being a count:

count number of observations where

> Closing.Date.Time <= Create.Date.Time

for each `Create.Date.Time` for each `Service.`

My starting point is `ddply (df, .(Service, Create.Date.Time), ...)`, but i am having trouble with my function since the values depend on my `Create.Date.Time` and I do not know how to write that. Could someone help me please?

I want to end up with a data frame like this:

```
 Service        Create.Date.Time      Num.Closed
  AV            2013-06-01 12:59:00      0
  SERVICE684793 2013-06-02 07:56:00      0
  SERVICE684793 2013-06-02 09:39:00      1
  SERVICE684793 2013-06-03 07:20:00      1
  SERVICE684796 2013-06-02 14:14:00      0
  SERVICE684797 2013-06-02 17:20:00      0
  SERVICE684839 2013-06-03 08:02:00      0
  SERVICE684841 2013-06-03 08:04:00      0
  SERVICE684841 2013-06-03 08:04:00      0
  SERVICE684841 2013-06-03 08:08:00      3
```

Comment: In the dataset you showed. `with(df, Closing.Date.Time <=Create.Date.Time)# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE`.  There is only one row that is TRUE.  I am not sure how you got `3` in the expected output.

Comment: I actually want to have a cumulative count, I typed the expected data frame myself, For example, for Create.Date.Time of line 10 of my data frame, there are three observations of that service with closing time <= the Create.Date.Time of that observation

Comment: Could you provide your dataframe using `dput(df)` where `df` is your dataframe?

Comment: @user3770767. For the `SERVICE684797` row, it seems like `Closing.date.time <= Create.Date.Time'.  So, Num.Closed would be `1`?

Comment: @akrun, no it is not, for the reason that the closing date is the 2013.06.03, whereas the opening date is 2013.06.02. So the closing date is after the opening one. I have tried modifying your code to include the date as well. No success yet :-(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure how the data.frame you want to end up with relates to the question you asked since the results. aren't the one you describe. Could you perhaps write the loop that you would use if there is no other alternative?

If you want (as you wrote) the:

count number of observations where

```
Closing.Date.Time <= Create.Date.Time
```

for each `Create.Date.Time` for each `Service`, then a good way to go would be to use the `data.table` package. In that case, your data is:

```
       Create.Date.Time       Service   Closing.Date.Time
 1: 2013-06-01 12:59:00            AV 2013-06-01 13:59:00
 2: 2013-06-02 07:56:00 SERVICE684793 2013-06-02 08:59:00
 3: 2013-06-02 09:39:00 SERVICE684793 2013-06-03 12:01:00
 4: 2013-06-02 14:14:00 SERVICE684796 2013-06-02 14:55:00
 5: 2013-06-02 17:20:00 SERVICE684797 2013-06-03 12:06:00
 6: 2013-06-03 07:20:00 SERVICE684793 2013-06-03 07:39:00
 7: 2013-06-03 08:02:00 SERVICE684839 2013-06-03 12:09:00
 8: 2013-06-03 08:04:00 SERVICE684841 2013-06-04 08:05:00
 9: 2013-06-03 08:04:00 SERVICE684841 2013-06-05 08:06:00
10: 2013-06-03 08:08:00 SERVICE684841 2013-06-03 08:08:00
```

where the dates and times are `POSIXct` format.

Then:

```
dt[, sum(Closing.Date.Time <= Create.Date.Time ), by = c('Service', 'Create.Date.Time')]
```

would result in

```
         Service    Create.Date.Time V1
1:            AV 2013-06-01 12:59:00  0
2: SERVICE684793 2013-06-02 07:56:00  0
3: SERVICE684793 2013-06-02 09:39:00  0
4: SERVICE684796 2013-06-02 14:14:00  0
5: SERVICE684797 2013-06-02 17:20:00  0
6: SERVICE684793 2013-06-03 07:20:00  0
7: SERVICE684839 2013-06-03 08:02:00  0
8: SERVICE684841 2013-06-03 08:04:00  0
9: SERVICE684841 2013-06-03 08:08:00  1
```

Which is what you described.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fully understand the problem as there is one instance where the expected output shown is different from the output I am getting.  If that is just a typo:

#### data

```
 df <-   structure(list(Create.Date.Time = structure(c(1370105940, 1370174160, 
 1370180340, 1370196840, 1370208000, 1370258400, 1370260920, 1370261040, 
 1370261040, 1370261280), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
 Service = c("AV", "SERVICE684793", "SERVICE684793", "SERVICE684796", 
"SERVICE684797", "SERVICE684793", "SERVICE684839", "SERVICE684841", 
"SERVICE684841", "SERVICE684841"), Closing.Date.Time = structure(c(1370109540, 
1370177940, 1370275260, 1370199300, 1370275560, 1370259540, 
1370275740, 1370347500, 1370433960, 1370261280), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "")), .Names = c("Create.Date.Time", "Service", 
"Closing.Date.Time"), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), class = "data.frame")
```

Extract the time from the `POSIXct` class

```
library(lubridate)

dfNew <- within(df, {
            Createtime <- period_to_seconds(hms(strftime(Create.Date.Time, "%H:%M:%S")))
         Closingtime <- period_to_seconds(hms(strftime(Closing.Date.Time, "%H:%M:%S")))})

dfNew <- dfNew[order(dfNew$Service),] #not that necessary
```

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dfNew)[,Num.Closed := cumsum(unlist(lapply(1:.N, function(i) sum(Closingtime[1:i] <=Createtime[i])))),
   by=Service][,c(2,1,6), with=FALSE] 
#              Service    Create.Date.Time Num.Closed
 #1:            AV 2013-06-01 12:59:00          0
 #2: SERVICE684793 2013-06-02 07:56:00          0
 #3: SERVICE684793 2013-06-02 09:39:00          1
 #4: SERVICE684793 2013-06-03 07:20:00          1
 #5: SERVICE684796 2013-06-02 14:14:00          0
 #6: SERVICE684797 2013-06-02 17:20:00          1
 #7: SERVICE684839 2013-06-03 08:02:00          0
 #8: SERVICE684841 2013-06-03 08:04:00          0
 #9: SERVICE684841 2013-06-03 08:04:00          0
#10: SERVICE684841 2013-06-03 08:08:00          3
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I feel completely stupid, but is there any way of combining the date and time before extracting the time with 'period_to_seconds'? because the comparison of date/time should take the date in consideration as well...